# "Kein Stück" What does it mean?

Tags: meaning

Watching a German movie and people there keep saying "Kein Stück". Is it some sort of slang? "No pieces" makes no sense. Thank you.

Comment: Although most readers will have an idea what "Kein Stück" means, you should provide the context in which it appears. Theoretically it could be the answer to the question  "Möchtest Du ein Stück Kuchen?"

Answer (score 8):

It is some sort of slang, or at least rather informal speech. Literally *kein Stück* translates to *not a piece* (*no pieces* would be *keine Stücke*) and means as much as "not at all". As [Javatasse](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/33503/javatasse) mentions in a comment, a good translation is also "not even a tiny bit".

There is also *ein Stück weit*, which is the opposite and means "a little bit", "to a certain degree".

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. "Not at all" makes sense.

Comment: I would translate the sprit of the expression with "not even a tiny bit".

Comment: @Javatasse Good point! I added this to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

This most likely is slang for *überhaupt nicht*.

Answer (score 3):

Ganz analog dazu ist auch das verbreitete "kein bisschen."

```
A: "Du frierst doch!" 
B: "Kein bisschen/Kein Stück."
```

Es bedeutet so viel wie "not a bit" oder "to no part".

Comment: Je nach Kontext kann "kein bisschen" passen. Aber bitte nicht "Du frierst doch! Kein Stück."

Comment: Deutschlernen beinhaltet nicht nur Schriftsprache, Hochdeutsch und eigenen Ausdruck sondern auch das passive Verstehen anderer. Ich selbst benutze "kein Stück" nicht, aber ich will ja verstehen, was andere sagen wollen.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "Kein Stück" depends a bit on context.

Literally (like in @jonathan.scholback extended answer) in questions like "Would you want/like..." it can be used as a direct, a little bit rude, answer of "Not at all".

In a negotiation this phrase changes its meaning. For example on the question "Could you agree a little bit more with me that...?" ("Würden Sie mit mir einhergehen,dass...") the phrase becomes more like "Not a chance". Switches from meaning "I do not want anything" to "I will not budge".

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to extend Jonathan's answer of "ein Stück weit" to the comparison layer. It's common to use "ein Stück" and "kein Stück" for **comparisons** (especially if slight deltas are focused):

"Du bist kein Stück besser als er." --> "You are not at all better then him!"

It's also worth to mention the equivalent version with "**My**" (semantically quite the epsilon from differential mathematics):

"Du bist kein My besser als er".

Further on, the older and not that common "**Deut**" can be used for many scenarios too:

"Du bist keinen Deut besser als er" --> "You are not at all better then him!"

But in contrast to "My", its common usage fields are a bit reduced. So it's not common to say "Wir sind keinen Deut weiter gekommen". --> "We didn't proceed any further." Maybe this could be the content of a separate question in doubt here.

It's also common to use it within imperative structures that yield quite harsh or absolute aspects: "Keinen Schritt weiter!" --> "Do not move any further!"

Answer (score 1):

**The phrase *[kein Stück](https://www.dwds.de/wb/kein%20St%C3%BCck)* means "not at all".**

In this phrase, *Stück* has the meaning of "a certain distance" or "a little bit". The phrase *kein Stück* – literally "not even a tiny bit" – is the opposite of *ein Stück weit*, literally "a small distance", which means "somewhat".

*Examples*

> Ein Stück weit vertraue ich ihm. (I trust him a little. / I trust him somewhat.)
> Ich vertraue ihm kein Stück. (I don't trust him at all.)

English phrases such as "I trust him only as far as I can throw him" have the same underlying concept of trust measured in distance.